# ¿Somos demasiados exigentes con las preguntas de los usuarios?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

Con preocupación veo algo que siento casi como una obsesión de cerrar preguntas por que supuéstamente no se entienden o por que sean demasiados amplios. Concuerdo que estas razones existen, pero lo estamos aplicando bien?

Un ejemplo: esta pregunta ya tiene tres votos (a la hora de mi pregunta) para cierre por demasiado amplio:

[¿Cómo detectar la orientacion(horizontal o vertical) en android de la pantalla en la clase java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51511/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-la-orientacionhorizontal-o-vertical-en-android-de-la-pantalla-e)

Es levemente menos elaborada que esta pregunta extremadamente parecida en SOen:
[how-can-i-get-the-current-screen-orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663665/how-can-i-get-the-current-screen-orientation)

Alguien me puede explicar porque una respuesta así es perfectamente aceptable con una multitud de respuestas en SOen, pero cuando se trata de programación de personas que hablan español, no puede existir esta variedad de respuestas?

Eso es solamente un ejemplo, cada día veo ejemplos de votos de cierre que encuentro casi paranoico, como si el mundo colapsaría si permitíamos preguntas que no no son calidad de wiki o para una publicación de un libro.

¿Porqué es necesario que andamos con una actitud en SOes de "en caso de duda, mejor oprimimos la pregunta" mientras la apertura para aceptar preguntas es mucho más mente abierto en SOen?

Si una pregunta que en realidad inspira respuestas de mala calidad existe, hay suficiente tiempo y usuarios con privilegio de votar para cerrarla cuando ocurre. Las respuestas malas se pueden poner a voto por eliminación.

¿Soy el único que ve mucho daño para la plataforma en exageradamente cerrar preguntas aun que ya tienen buenas respuestas por los razones equivocados, en vez de simplemente confiar que por el tiempo se encuentran usuarios que pueden ayudar con mejorar los formatos?

Y finalmente dejo este pensamiento: si ocurren muchas preguntas a un nivel muy simple, no sería lógico de asumir que en español existe mucha necesidad de responder a este nivel de preguntas, porque no hay la misma oferta de buena documentación o tutoriales en español como por ejemplo en ingles o alemán?

Yo siento que con las practicas ahora enviemos el mensaje: "Aprende ingles mejor, weon, para que te capacitas antes de atreverte de preguntar aquí", y dudo que eso aporta en hacer SOes lo que podría ser: la primer y mejor plataforma para ayuda en problemas de programación y desarrollo.

¿Que más observaciones existen sobre el tema?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54428/discussion-on-question-by-stefan-nolde-somos-demasiados-exigentes-con-las-pregu).

Answer (score 7):

Partiendo de mi experiencia como usuario reciente de esSO creo que sí, que en la versión castellana de SO hay un cierto espíritu restrictivo el cual no hace sino **empobrecer** una plataforma que puede servir no solamente de ayuda en forma de pregunta-respuesta sino incluso de información.

Ya sé que alguno dirá: *¡Pero esSO no es un blog!* Y yo digo, no lo es, pero podría serlo, al menos en ciertos casos... como lo es en inglés en ciertas preguntas-respuestas. ¿El motivo? **La falta de contenido de calidad en castellano** de casi todos los lenguajes y plataformas informáticos. Es más, si hiciese la función de blog creo que ayudaría a enriquecer a esta comunidad y atraería a gente capacitada y preparada a participar en ella y compartir contenido de calidad. Cuando hablo de *hacer de función de blog* me refiero a que no debe escandalizarnos de que existan ciertas respuestas largas, explicativas y detalladas en esSO.

Por ejemplo: hace pocos días hice una pregunta acerca de jQuery 3, nueva versión de la librería, con la intención de que la respuesta diese detalles de las principales novedades de la misma. Antes de las dos horas la pregunta tenía a al menos tres usuarios clamando que la cierren. ¿Motivo del cierre? **Demasiado amplia.** Pero yo me decía: podría ser una pregunta que provoque una respuesta extensa, primero porque es una nueva librería, segundo porque jQuery es riquísima como librería. Pero luego preguntaba cosas muy concretas sobre la misma.

¿Por qué fue considerada como demasiado amplia? Lo ignoro. Además, ninguno de los usuarios que clamaban el cierre tuvo la delicadeza de escribir un comentario en la pregunta indicando que la había marcado para cierre, o explicando el motivo por el cual la consideraba demasiado amplia. No es obligatorio, pero creo que al menos por delicadeza y responsabilidad hemos de dar la cara cuando somos los primeros en marcar algo para cierre, indicando los motivos.

Y ¿por qué digo que tal actitud empobrece a una comunidad emergente como esSO? Primero, por la escasez de contenido en castellano y segundo porque si hoy nos vamos a Google y buscamos "jQuery 3 novedades" o algo por el estilo vemos que la pregunta condenada a cierre antes de sus dos horas de existencia aparece en la primera página de los resultados de búsqueda. Entonces, ¿por qué no ofrecer a la comunidad informática de habla hispana la posibilidad de consultar una pregunta-respuesta amplia, detallada, con contenido de calidad, totalmente en castellano... y extensa?

Es más, creo que es una de las vías por las que una comunidad como esta crecerá. Sino, seguirá siendo pobre y será quizá útil para hacer crecer el ego de dos o tres, pero no para una gran mayoría de gente que empieza y aprendería más si lee contenido en el idioma de Cervantes.

Y créanme que a mi me daría igual seguir aprendiendo en SO en inglés, me defiendo bien leyendo en inglés sobre informática, pero en enSO no aportaría nada, porque no es mi lengua materna y porque hay mucha gente aportando. Aquí sí me gustaría aportar, pero cuando te encuentras con ciertas murallas que con el clic de un botón descalifican algo que has preparado durante media hora o una hora,la verdad no te quedas con ganas de seguir aportando.

Me gustaría que haya cada vez más contenido bueno de informática en castellano y creo sinceramente que esSO está siendo pionero en esto. Espero que continúe creciendo.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54427/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-somos-demasiados-exigentes-con-las-preguntas).

Answer (score 2):

> Alguien me puede explicar porque una respuesta así es perfectamente aceptable con una multitud de respuestas en SOen, pero cuando se trata de programación de personas que hablan español, no puede existir esta variedad de respuestas?

Somos comunidades distintas y como tales la comunidad decide que es aceptable o no siempre y cuando se tengan en cuenta las normas definidas en el sitio.

El caso concreto que expones lo considero apropiado para el sitio (y su NO cierre y votos positivos indican que la comunidad la ha aceptado y la considera una buena pregunta).

> ¿Soy el único que ve mucho daño para la plataforma en exageradamente cerrar preguntas aun que ya tienen buenas respuestas por los razones equivocados, en vez de simplemente confiar que por el tiempo se encuentran usuarios que pueden ayudar con mejorar los formatos?

Que estemos en Beta no significa que la calidad del sitio tenga que ser menor y me parece genial que así sea.

Lo ideal es mantener un umbral alto de calidad pero siempre intentando formar y mostrar a los usuarios como se debe hacer. Estamos en beta para construir una comunidad viva y sana.

> ¿Porqué es necesario que andamos con una actitud en SOes de "en caso de duda, mejor oprimimos la pregunta" mientras la apertura para aceptar preguntas es mucho más mente abierto en SOen?

No concuerdo con tu opinión. Los datos y reportes que recibo indican lo contrario: desgraciadamente no puedo compartir esos reportes para mostrar la información pero si que puedo contar que SOes es masa sana en preguntas.

Answer (score 2):

"Ligeramente más elaborada" no puede ser lo mismo que la diferencia entre a) una pregunta sin ningún intento de escribir el código y atacar el problema, y b) una pregunta donde escriben un código y dicen que ya tienen algo pero algo más no funciona.

Lo que se debería pedir es que, si esta es una comunidad de personas que escriben código con algún fin, las preguntas no deben ser solicitudes para que nos escriban el código.

Además, en SO en inglés se es aún más estricto con que se incluya un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable. Eso de que "aprende inglés, weon" no tienen ningún sentido.