# ¿Que hacer cuando respuesta es la solución de una pregunta pero fomenta a los usuarios a hacer preguntas que no cumplen con las reglas?

Tags: discusión

Me explico, se realizo [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66499/capturar-datos-de-un-formulario-y-guardarlos-como-un-objeto-en-un-json/) y tuvo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66499/capturar-datos-de-un-formulario-y-guardarlos-como-un-objeto-en-un-json/66542#66542).

La pregunta no cumple con las reglas puesto que el usuario no demuestra que intento o busco como hacerlo por si mismo, posteriormente fue puesta en espera; antes de eso un usuario respondió, pero mi punto de vista los usuarios que responden preguntas tan fáciles es por que quieren ganarse puntos fáciles.

Lo pregunto porque ya he visto lo mismo varias veces, con preguntas que hacen los usuarios para que les "hagan la tarea".

¿Se debe reportar la respuesta o simplemente estoy mal?

Comment: No me queda del todo claro. ¿Reportar como qué? ¿Qué es lo que podría hacer un moderador que los usuarios no podamos hacer? ¿Y qué pensás que deberíamos haber en estos casos?

Comment: No veo que las respuestas tengan opción de uno votar para eliminar, (claro, a menos que yo aun no la visualice) por eso digo "reportar". Yo solo puedo colocarle negativos y reportarla. Pero yo digo que deben ser eliminadas las respuestas de ese tipo, hasta esperar que el usuario que hizo la pregunta la modifique y especifique su problema si es que, anteriormente, busco una solución acerca de su incógnita.

Comment: Desde mi visión, no se debe culpar a quien responde, sino a quien pregunta... Con 500 de reputación (en beta) se puede votar para cerrar una pregunta. Eso es suficiente para que nadie responda... En cuanto a las respuestas antes de que se cierre, se puede comentar explicando los motivos por los cuales no conviene responder a preguntas incompletas, pero no sancionar a quien intenta aportar contenido (y estoy hablando del caso general, no de la pregunta específica que citaste como ejemplo)

Comment: Ok gracias por tu punto de vista :D

Comment: hasta ahora lo puse como comentario porque me interesaba contrastar puntos de vista... Pero creo que más allá de los puntos de vista, los moderadores están para los casos en que los usuarios no pueden hacer nada, y creo que en estos casos la propia comunidad puede moderarlos, sin necesidad de emitir reportes

Comment: Buenas, soy el susodicho de la respuesta. Después de un par de comentarios con @PabloContreras al respecto decidí que tenía razón en lo que decía y retiré la respuesta. Me metí recientemente en StackOverflow en español precisamente porque es una lástima que no tenga toda la acogida que tiene su hermano en inglés. No es una situación fácil que tratar pero en esencia todo se puede reducir a preguntarse si se prefiere actividad (de preguntas y respuestas) o seleccionar

Comment: Por cierto, @PabloContreras en los comentarios de dicha respuesta, me comentabas que había una pregunta en el meta sobre este tipo de cuestiones pero que no encontrabas, creo haber encontrado dos que encajaban con lo que decías. Las enlazo en el comentario para tenerlas como referencia: [la más relevante](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/840/qu%C3%A9-deber%C3%ADamos-hacer-a-las-preguntas-del-tipo-no-he-intentado-pero-quiero-resp) y [ligeramente relacionada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1466/somos-demasiados-exigentes-con-las-preguntas-de-los-usuarios)

Comment: @frikinside si, es la primera que indicas "la mas relevante" y ok, la intensión no es atacarte, solo para que sepas que el sitio no es google y tampoco se fomenta a la flojera, un simple comentario "edita tu pregunta y coloca lo que has intentado" y así el usuario aprenderá para una próxima vez. Saludos :D

Comment: Creo que este problema es el que más me desanima a comentar y votar en SO en español. Aca es muy común ver que responden con código que el OP no ha intentado escribir y mucho menos se encuentra una traza de error de ese intento.

Answer (score 1):

Considero que cuando existe una *respuesta **correcta***, en cuanto a que soluciona el problema, pero en consideración de uno se trata de una *respuesta **incorrecta*** ya que realiza más daño que beneficio, lo más apropiado es publicar un comentario o bien invitar al autor a un chat, justo como se hizo en [el caso referido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66499/65).

> Nota: Lo anterior lo pueden ver los miembros con el privilegio [Acceso a herramientas de moderación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Por ejemplo, se le puede advertir al autor de la respuesta que:

- Está fomentando malas preguntas.
- Las malas preguntas pueden ser cerradas e incluso eliminadas. En caso de que la pregunta sea eliminada, al respuesta también será eliminada.
- Una pregunta con un mal título, tiene pocas probabilidades de atraer lectores y por ende es probable que la respuesta tenga poco impacto.

> Nota: También está la posibilidad de recibir votos negativos, por ser un respuesta no útil desde ciertas perspectivas pero no voy a abordar este caso, pues se requeriría una explicación muy larga y de todas formas resultaría polémica y prestarse a discusiones largas, siendo que la pregunta se refiere a si **se debe reportar o no**.

Además de recomendarle que busque primero que se mejore la pregunta ya sea editando la pregunta misma o bien sugiriendo al autor la forma de proceder para mejorar su pregunta.

En cuanto al [privilegio reportar publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), en el artículo de ayuda enlazado se incluyen enlaces a guías específicas, **en inglés**, de *cuando **sí** reportar* pero no todas las guías incluyen orientación sobre *cuando **no** reportar*.

En el caso específico de las respuestas, existe el reporte "No es una respuesta" que en pocas palabras se utiliza para publicaciones fuera de tema (off-topic / que no vienen al caso) en relación de la pregunta. Obviamente, este no debe usarse cuando se trata de una *respuesta correcta*.

El reporte "Necesita la intervención de un moderador" se reserva para casos en los que quien reporta no cuenta con otros medios para solucionar la situación. En el caso particular de las respuestas, me parece que esto debe limitarse a casos en los casos de comportamientos inadecuados como las "guerras de ediciones".

Cabe hacer notar que existen medallas para premiar la buenas respuestas tales como *Buena Respuesta*, *Respuesta Interesante* y *Excelente Respuesta* que se otorgan con base en la puntuación de votos de la respuesta, independientemente de la pregunta.

Así mismo, existe una medalla dorada para el caso específico de una *respuesta interesante* (puntuación 10 o más) a una *mala pregunta*

> Reversión
>
> - Proporcionar una respuesta con una puntuación de +20 a una pregunta con una puntuación de -5

Entonces, si se va publicar una respuesta a una mala pregunta, "valdría la pena" si se trata de *una muy buena respuesta*.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, esa medalla "Reversión", ¿puedes pasar un caso para entenderla?

Comment: @PabloContreras: En español aún no tenemos casos por lo que te dejo la  lista de los casos en el sitio en inglés -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal